# Вектор двумерных массивов

Tags: c++

Необходимо создать динамический вектор, в котором хранятся двумерные массивы символов, интуитивно я решил написать так:

```
vector <char> input[8][8];
```

Встал вопрос, правилен ли такой синтаксис, и как собственно добавлять в него элементы (двумерные массивы).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы написали - двумерный массив из векторов.

Comment: Думаю вам нужен vector<char**>

Answer (score 0):

я думаю будет легче сделать вектор строк

```
std::vector<std::string> input(8);
```

что насчет `vector <char> input[8][8]`, так писать нельзя. vector - динамический массив, а обычные двумерные динамические массивы описываются так

```
char **arr = new char*[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    arr[i] = new char[8];
```

и зачем использовать вектор если вы заранее хотите задать размер двумерного массива как 8x8?